# Mime Type lost in upload to Google Cloud Storage via Blobstore API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-storage

When I'm uploading a file to Google Cloud Storage, using a Python App Engine Flask instance, if I upload a file using a normal file input, MIME type is respected, but if I upload a file using AJAX, the file type is not detected and *application/octet-stream* is assigned.

What should I do? is this important at all ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Which Cloud Storage API are you using? Also, what does the AJAX request look like?

Comment: I am not using any Cloud Storage API but the [Blobstore API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage) from App Engine. I'm doing a post request via JavaScript  Thanks !

Comment: Seconding request from @BrandonYarbrough. Can you include the ajax code? You may simply need to inspect the file and set a header, or something else about the ajax file upload is off.